# Does "Process up" exist in English?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

> I will leave her alone for now so that she can **process** things **up**.

I think for a sentence like this one, "process up" makes a suitable fit. I assume it means "absorb", but I didn't find it used according to my research, nor I found its meaning. And although [Ngram shows some results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=process+things%2Cprocess+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprocess%20things%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cprocess%20up%3B%2Cc0) for "process up", I didn't find it used as a whole phrase in Google Books.

Does **process up** exist in English? And can it convey the meaning of "absorb" which is *to take something in, especially gradually*?

---

The sentence is said by **A** to herself in an informal writing story. **B** has talked harshly to **C** and told **C** things that would change **C**'s life to the worse. Then, **B** leaves **A** and **C** alone in the room, and that's when **A** says the sentence to herself intending **C** in her speech.

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard "up" used with "to process." At best it's very awkward, if not wrong. I think we'd need to see more context to make any conclusions about the intended meaning, or to suggest alternatives.

Comment: I've added more context. Hope it would indicate exactly what I intend.

Comment: Your cited text looks like a learner's attempt to reproduce what native speakers would express as *...so that she can [**finish** (things) up*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=finish+things+up&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfinish%20things%20up%3B%2Cc0) (where ***things*** is optional, but *wouldn't* normally be included). It's not idiomatic to use ***process*** in this construction.

Comment: If you dig into some of those Ngram results, none of them are using **process up** as a phrasal verb.  Instead, you'll see sentences like, "[he] divides the process up into a clearly defined set of operations," or, "The result of blowing the Control process up is shown in Figure 3."  Those are just situations where the separate words **process** and **up** happen to be adjacent to each other in a sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _ I don't know why it looks like this. I used "process up" as I *remember* it being used in such constructions and in similar situations.

Comment: @CanadianYankee _ I assumed it would be like that since I found similar examples of "process up" usage in Google Search results. Thank you for informing me of this point.

Comment: TasneemZH: Well, I wouldn't argue the toss with a native speaker. People say whatever they say, and it's not up to me to tell them they shouldn't. But I wouldn't advise *learners* to think it's okay to play fast and loose with "unusual, uncommon, ad-hoc" phrasal verb forms like this. It might be relevant that what I think of as "phrasal verbs" can normally by used intransitively. So ***to step up*** qualifies, because we can say ***He stepped up***, but ***to think up*** doesn't work because we can't say ***He thought up*** as a standalone sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers _ This is indeed very beneficial advice. Thank you for it and for the suggestion above! It was interesting to know the phrasal verbs trick, but as a learner, I *think* I would, at some point, misuse it besides the fact that it is not always the case with figuring out the right phrasal verbs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to express this idea in common English, but unfortunately your example is not one of them.  Consider as alternatives:  process (without the "up"), absorb, mull things over, think things over/through, let the gears turn, reflect (or pause to reflect), chew on the idea, contemplate, soak up (as suggested by @Bee), and probably many more.

Take note that many of these are idioms, and some more or less formal than others.  Which you choose may depend on factors of your audience which you do not specify in the question.

Comment: **Thank you** for the many alternatives although I just wanted to clarify about "process up".

Answer (score 2):

I think the phrase you might be looking for is "soak up".

Generally I think this would only ever be used metaphorically so it might be worth clarifying:

> I will leave her alone for now so that she can soak up the information.

Do let me know if that's not the what you were looking for!

Comment: It works according to its meaning in the dictionaries. It is a synonym to "absorb", and you stated that it can be used metaphorically. But instead of "the information", I would write "things". Thank you!

Comment: @TasneemZH "To soak up (the) _things_" (instead of _information_) doesn't work for me, but you could say "to soak everything up" or, more idiomatically, "to let it all sink in."

Comment: @TypeIA _ Seems as great suggestions. I may go with the latter. Thanks!